# Create new home directory for a user in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts, webserver

A quick question on user management in Ubuntu 10.04.

I encounter the following practice in some deployment script for web server:

```
mkdir /home/www-data
cd /home/www-data
wget http://somesite.com/static/some_package.zip
unzip some_package.zip
rm some_package.zip
chown -R www-data:www-data some_package
```

It seems to me that no user/group has been explicitly created as '`www-data`', unless the `chown` command does that? If so, does that mean that I can run stuff inside `/home/www-data/` as user '`www-data`' in some server start-up script? Or do I need to do extra permission configurations?

Answer (score 0):

On Debian-based systems, the user and group `www-data` are usually created at installation time, for use by web servers.

If they didn't exist, `chown` wouldn't create them – it would display an error message instead.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. one more thing, do I need to use chown to change the ownership of every time I copy a package/folder to `/home/www-data/` when I deploy?